# Payment Shipping option does not show on checkout express and incorrectly on default checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, free-shipping

Im having trouble with the checkout process. It tells me:
"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Im trying to do the checkout in Sweden and there should not be any "price check" on addresses, since we have Free shipping enabled.

I have filled in all the fields in the address.

And when using Single page checkout it only says:
"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

A bit frustrating. Googled alot and read several suggestions but none has worked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as you have only free shipping enable, does your cart qualify for free shipping ?

Comment: "I guess", how can I check that? I have set no specific rules for the free shipping